# How to export nested array data from mongodb to csv

Tags: arrays, mongodb, csv

I have the below json format of document in my collection in mongodb.Now i need to export this data into csv with only specified fields and i dont want 
frequency_serving "Never" value object(Under VFoodDetails Array)in csv.What i tried the below command

```
-c FrequencyQuestionForm --type=csv --fields data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Group_Id,data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Study_Name -q '{"data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Study_Id":"1"}' --out D:/MongoDBReports/Book1.csv
```

it throws an error like this

> "too many positional arguments: [dbmongo 27017 FormDataBase
>   FrequencyQuestionForm 'data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Group_
>   Id,data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Study_Name']
>   2018-02-12T17:37:58.012+0530    try 'mongoexport --help' for more
>   information"

```
[
      {
        "_id": "5a6026e29cbcdc48083dae1a",
        "data": {
          "formList": [
            {
              "IdentificationDetails": [
                {
                  "Status": "Data Entry Completed",
                  "Form_Id": 1,
                  "Interviewer_Name": "NAGARAJ.P",
                  "Group_Id": 9,
                  "Study_Id": "1",
                  "Study_Name": "INDIAB",
                  "Created_Emp_Id": "1",
                  "Form_Name": "Food Frequency Questionnarie",
                  "Visit_No": "1",
                  "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                  "Interview_Date": "2009-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                  "Volunteer_Name": "RAJENDRA PAWAR"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "VFoodDetails": [
                {
                  "Portion_Size": 15,
                  "Serving_Size": "0",
                  "Food_Id": 737,
                  "Value": "0",
                  "Portion_Tool": 18,
                  "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                  "Meal_Session": 121,
                  "Frequency_Serving": "Daily"
                },
                {
                  "Portion_Size": 168,
                  "Serving_Size": "0",
                  "Food_Id": 740,
                  "Value": "0",
                  "Portion_Tool": 177,
                  "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                  "Meal_Session": 121,
                  "Frequency_Serving": "Never"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": "5a6026e29cbcdc46783dae1a",
        "data": {
          "formList": [
            {
              "IdentificationDetails": [
                {
                  "Status": "Data Entry Completed",
                  "Form_Id": 1,
                  "Interviewer_Name": "NAGARAJ.P",
                  "Group_Id": 9,
                  "Study_Id": "1",
                  "Study_Name": "INDIAB",
                  "Created_Emp_Id": "1",
                  "Form_Name": "Food Frequency Questionnarie",
                  "Visit_No": "1",
                  "Volunteer_Id": "R270176",
                  "Interview_Date": "2009-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                  "Volunteer_Name": "KUMARAN PAWAR"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "VFoodDetails": [
                {
                  "Portion_Size": 15,
                  "Serving_Size": "0",
                  "Food_Id": 737,
                  "Value": "0",
                  "Portion_Tool": 18,
                  "Volunteer_Id": "R270176",
                  "Meal_Session": 121,
                  "Frequency_Serving": "Never"
                },
                {
                  "Portion_Size": 168,
                  "Serving_Size": "0",
                  "Food_Id": 740,
                  "Value": "0",
                  "Portion_Tool": 177,
                  "Volunteer_Id": "R270176",
                  "Meal_Session": 121,
                  "Frequency_Serving": "Weekly"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding the `--fields`  with either double or single quotes. I also think you need to specify the first array element in the fields export.

Using the documents you’ve provided:

```
 mongoexport --host localhost --port 40001 -d test -c foo  --type=csv --fields "data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Group_Id,data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Study_Name" --out Book1.csv
```

Output:

```
2018-02-13T19:32:50.172+0000    connected to: localhost:40001
2018-02-13T19:32:50.173+0000    exported 2 records
[mongodb@localhost ~]$ cat Book1.csv

data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Group_Id,data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Study_Name
9,INDIAB
9,INDIAB
```

Comment: Sorry, its not working. i am getting the same error.

Comment: @srikasi what version of mongo are you running? Please see my updated answer, it’s working on my dev machine running v3.6 on Linux

Comment: Thanks N3i1,it is working fine but what i want in my output is:   data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Group_Id,data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Study_Name,VFoodDetails.Portion_Size,VFoodDetails.Portion_Size,Serving_Size,
VFoodDetails.Frequency_Serving
9,INDIAB,15,0,Never
9,INDIAB,168,0,Weekly

Comment: @srikasi My answer is based on helping you solve the error you were  receiving regarding: `"too many positional arguments"`, which it has!!. How to display your data in the way you wish is another Q&A